# PayPal Login with Java Rest API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am currently trying to integrate a PayPal Login into my JSF application.

The user should be redirected to PayPal, login and then be redirected back to our site. With the redirected token, I want to fetch the users email.

I am using the latest Java Restful API and used the exact sample PayPal provided.

```
Map<String, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    configurationMap.put("mode", "sandbox");

    APIContext apiContext = new APIContext();
    apiContext.setConfigurationMap(configurationMap);

    List<String> scopelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopelist.add("openid");
    scopelist.add("email");
    String redirectURI = "https://22af922.ngrok.com/";

    ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
    clientCredentials.setClientID("my_client_id");

    String redirectUrl = Session.getRedirectURL(redirectURI, scopelist, apiContext, clientCredentials);
```

Generating the redirect url works fine, however, on redirect, it keeps telling me that the redirect_uri does not match the redirect_uri in my application settings, even though I am using the exact same url I have setup in my PayPal app.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following.

1. Go to http://developer.paypal.com/ and login
2. Go to Sandbox > Accounts
3. Click on the -developer account -> Profile -> API Credentials
4. Make sure the return url is the same as the return url you are trying to use
5. Press Save

Even though the return url in those settings was equal to the one in my app settings, just using the save button in that specific place did the trick. I have absolutely no idea why this fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the "redirectURI" has the same URI as the one in the REST apps in your Developer account? Steps:

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com and login with your PayPal account
2. Click 'Dashboard'
3. On the REST apps page, select the REST app that you use in your Java application (the client ID and secret is the same)
4. Under 'SANDBOX APP SETTING' section, check whether you use the same url as the one in 'Return URL' field

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same url.